# How can I prevent the click event from firing twice with Google Tag Manager and React in AEM?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, aem, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM with react coding on AEM (Adope Experience Manager). As you can see in the image the loading and scroll events are working fine but click event fires twice every time I click. With every click it fires dataLayer.push() then shows an error then fires dataLayer.push() again. I can see that on console and it reflects to the report in GTM. The code I use as below.

```
   <script>
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            console.log("Test 5 ###");
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-######');
    </script>
```

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app</noscript><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-######" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"/></noscript>
```

[check the Image of chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsZPQ.png)

I did search online a lot of answers is to configure the events through GTM not GA I did this but still facing the same issue.